# How to resize QML TextField whenever parent form is resized

Tags: forms, qml, controls, anchor

I have a form and a `TextField` on it. The `TextField` size is fixed regardless of form size. I want it to be resized whenever form is resized (specially getting bigger when form is maximized). How to achieve this (a fix margin between the two is OK).

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import org.kde.plasma.plasmoid 2.0
import org.kde.plasma.core 2.0 as PlasmaCore
import org.kde.plasma.components 3.0 as PlasmaComponents

Item
{
  property alias cfg_mainText:       mainText.text

  anchors.centerIn:     parent

  ColumnLayout
   {

   RowLayout
    {
      Label { text: "Main" }
      TextField
      {
        id:               mainText
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        placeholderText:  "important text here"
        text:             ""
      }
    }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have one Item that contains your  `TextField` First of all you should set `id` for it and anchors, then say to your TextField that its width should be the same as Item.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")



    Item
    {
        id:txtField
        property alias cfg_mainText:       mainText.text
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: 240
        anchors.bottomMargin: 200
        anchors.leftMargin: 320
        anchors.rightMargin: 91


        ColumnLayout
        {

            RowLayout
            {
                Label { text: "Main" }
                TextField
                {
                    id:               mainText
                    width: txtField.width

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    placeholderText:  "important text here"
                    text:             ""
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```